Ordinary and extraordinary rays in uniaxial crystal
I've been learning about birefringence and have a question regarding optical axes.
Suppose we cut a uniaxial crystal parallel to its optical axis and perpendicular to the incidence plane, and have incident light coming in at an angle.
If we represent light as 2 components, one in the incidence plane and one perpendicular to it, it is clear that the perp component is the ordinary ray because it is perpendicular to the optical axis (and therefore travels with speed $c/n_o$ where $n_o$ is the index of the medium for ordinary rays), but what about the other component?
It is not parallel with the optical axis, so I don't think we can say it's an extraordinary ray.
I think there are 2 possibilities: Either the model of representing a light beam as 2 mutually perpendicular components is not sufficient here, or I don't understand what characterizes a ray as "ordinary" or "extraordinary."
In either case, your help would be very appreciated.


By definition, the extraordinary index depends on the angle $\theta$ between $\vec{k}$ and the optical axis. The ordinary ray is polarized perpenducular to the optical axis and the extaordinary ray is polarized in a plane containing the optical axis

The other ray is the extraordinary ray.

The main point is that the refractive index of plane-polarized light is determined by the electric displacement $\mathbf{D}$ (which is perpendicular to the wavevector) rather than the wavevector. If $\mathbf{D}$ is perpendicular to the optic axis, it is an ordinary ray and its refractive index will be $n_o$. This includes the case where the wavevector is parallel to the optic axis, which is probably what's counterintuitive. If the wavevector is at a nonzero angle $\theta$ to the optic axis and $\mathbf{D}$ lies in the plane spanned by them, it is an extraordinary ray. The main feature of such a ray is that the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is not parallel to $\mathbf{D}$ and has a component along the wavevector, which means that its Poynting vector is in a different direction from its wavevector. Its refractive index will be
$$\left(\frac{\sin^2\theta}{{n_e}^2} + \frac{\cos^2\theta}{{n_o}^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$
As expected, if $\theta=0$, this reduces to $n_o$.
